# NSDocument Directory & Loading Images Collection view

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, singleton, nsdocumentdirectory

I am developing an app like , Taking a picture from camera and saving them in array of dictionary and in nsdocument directory path in singleton class. i am showing the saved picture in collection view corresponding to each cell .
I have tried , but what i am getting is ,The collection view image is showing the same image in each cell .

Example the the array count is 2 , for 2 cells it showing the latest picture i.e the second picture .So please help me .
Code is shown below...

CameraVC Class

//while taking photos

```
-(IBAction)takephoto:(id)sender
{
tapCount += 1;
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection  = nil;
for(AVCaptureConnection *connection in StillImageOutput.connections)
{
    for(AVCaptureInputPort *port in  [connection inputPorts])
    {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]){
            videoConnection =connection;
            break;
        }}}

  [StillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error){

    if (imageDataSampleBuffer!=NULL) {
      NSData *imageData =[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];

       self.image = [ UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        int x = arc4random() % 100;
        NSTimeInterval secondsSinceUnixEpoch = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970];

      ImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d_%d",self.siteName,x,(int)secondsSinceUnixEpoch];

      [[SingletonImage singletonImage]SaveImageInNSdocumentAndCache:self.image withImageName:ImageName];
     [self.collection_View reloadData];
 }
   }];}
```

MY Collection View Methods

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[[SingletonImage singletonImage]arrayDict] count];}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CollectionViewCell *Cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//Loading images in collection view cell
Cell.image_View.image = [[SingletonImage singletonImage]ProvideImage:ImageName];

 return Cell;

  }
```

This is my Singleton Class

```
 #import "SingletonImage.h"
@implementation SingletonImage
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if ( self )
{
    self.arrayDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   self.imageDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
  }
return self;}

+(instancetype)singletonImage
{
static SingletonImage *singletonImage;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    singletonImage = [[SingletonImage alloc]init];
    });
return singletonImage;}
```

//Saving Image to array of dictionaries and nsdocument directory path

```
 -(void)SaveImageInNSdocumentAndCache:(UIImage *)image  withImageName:(NSString *)str
 {
//Saving image in array of dictionaries
[self.imageDict setObject:image forKey:str];
  [self.arrayDict insertObject:self.imageDict atIndex:0];
NSLog(@" array of dictionaries%@",self.arrayDict);
//Saving image in nsdocumnet directory path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = paths.firstObject;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *imageFolder = @"Photos";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyMMddHHmmss"];
   NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentDirectory,imageFolder];

BOOL isDir;
NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imagePath isDirectory:&isDir])
    if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:imagePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
        NSLog(@"Error: folder creation failed %@", documentDirectory);

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", imagePath, str] contents:nil attributes:nil];
[imageData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", imagePath, str] atomically:YES];}
```

//Provide the image if it is in dictionary or else provide from nsdocument directory path

```
   - (UIImage *)ProvideImage:(NSString *)text {

UIImage *Savedimage;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:text];
   if ([self.imageDict objectForKey:text])
   {
   Savedimage = [self.imageDict objectForKey:text];
    }
  else if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
  {

    Savedimage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSLog(@"%@",Savedimage);

        NSLog(@"File exists at the path");  }
    else
      {
        NSLog(@"Image doesnot exist");
      }


NSLog(@" the saved image is :%@",Savedimage);
 return Savedimage;}
```

VC.h file 
Here i declared the  nsstring

```
   @interface CameraViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource ,UICollectionViewDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
 {   NSString *ImageName;

  }
```

and ImageName is used in cell for item at index path method to get the image from singleton class.
I have tried what I know .

Comment: Please any one help me to do this

Comment: Check that your saved image is not overrite with same name

Comment: @Jecky , Ya it overriding with the same name .Please give a suggestion to relieve this

Comment: Use this code to give unique name.          NSString *myUniqueName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%u", @"YOURIMAGENAME", (NSUInteger)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]*10.0)];

Comment: @Jecky , if i give local variable like above , how can i pass the image name in cell for item at index path to get the image . Here **Cell.image_View.image = [[SingletonImage singletonImage]ProvideImage:ImageName];
**

Comment: So, You give name of your image like self.siteName . [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%u", %@, (NSUInteger)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]*10.0), self.siteName];

Comment: @Jecky ,Please check my update answer

Comment: @Jecky , self.sitename is another string i am just appending the string with my image name

Comment: So, what is your filename of image you saved to directory ? which name is overwritten ?

Comment: send me your code I will help you.Already I answered to your question 2 times.Again you asked now.

Comment: I wan to run your code and I will solve the issue.

Comment: @user3182143 ,how can i send to u ?through?

Comment: Upload your code in drop box.From there I can get it.